# nginx not passing through

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, containers, amazon-ecs

I am having an issue with nginx configuration not passing through to my app server.. I am using almost an exact replica of a conf file that is available for something else, just removed 443 stuff. My instances are in containers hosted on AWS ECS Fargate. I am passing in the `${NGINX_HOST}` variable, which is currently the URL of an ALB in front of my web app. Tried localhost, nothing really seems to change or do anything.

I am getting the nginx conf updated by creating my own container with my own conf file, uploading the container to docker hub and pulling from there as I'm doing testing.

Any thoughts on why this config isnt working would be appreciated, or ways to test what its pointing to while deployed.

```
map $sent_http_content_type $charset {
        ~^text/ utf-8;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name ${NGINX_HOST};

    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    Host               $host;

    location / {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_buffers 32 5m;
        proxy_buffer_size 5m;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://${NGINX_HOST}:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Nginx running in the same ECS task as your "backend" container? Or in separate ECS tasks? Your upstream configuration `server server:3000;` definitely looks wrong. It probably needs to be `server localhost:3000;`

Comment: It is running in the same task. I've tried changing that, that is the first obvious thing to look at. Ive set it to a whole bunch of stuff, localhost, variables, the web app container name .etc. Going to try `proxy_pass http://${NGINX_HOST}:3000` ... I've updated it to not use the backend upstream config and still no changes, just goes to nginx page

Comment: `localhost:3000` is the correct value to put there since it is in the same ECS Fargate task as the backend. You could use ECS Exec to get into the running container and verify your updated config file is there, and verify that you can `curl http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Yeah that is a good idea, Ive downloaded the container locally and checked the file and it was updated. I triedx tagging it as a specific version like 1.1 or 1.2 and pulling that so it would be certainly changed and still didnt fix it.
I have tried to exec into containers and the `aws ecs execute-command` doesn't work for me, I have gone through all of the instructions on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html and installed the separate SSM library on my windows machine. Will try to work through it.

Comment: If you just enabled ECS Exec for your service, you have to delete any running tasks and let new tasks be created before you can actually connect into them.